# In ASP.NET MVC, why Model and View can talk to each other? does it break the concept of MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

First of all, this is my first week on MVC 4

Microsoft claims the MVC will be the best web coding solution in the future based on three level framework.

1.Yet in their MVC concept, view and model can talk without controller, can any body tell me why they made that like a circle? What's the benefit behind it?

2.Without the view_state in web form, how can I know if a page is a post back?

Any open-mind ideas are welcomed!

Comment: MVC is not a MS concept; it is a programming pattern that MS is supporting. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/127624/what-is-mvc-really

Comment: You know if it's a POST-back (see answer by @Darin Dimitrov) by using proper GET and POST requests.

Best way to do it would be GET requests for GETting data, POST requests for submitting.

In MVC you can specify methods ONLY accept one type of HTTP Method

Comment: Not understand the meaning Geting data through 'GET', could you give me an example about it?@Stuart.Sklinar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.Yet in their MVC concept, view and model can talk without controller, can any body tell me why they made that like a circle?
>   What's the benefit behind it?

View and Model cannot talk without controller. Your view would never have known the Model if the Controller hasn't passed it to.

> 2.Without the view_state in web form, how can I know if a page is a post back?

Why would you even want to know such thing? This is an artificial concept invented specifically for classic WebForms to alleviate the stateless nature of the HTTP protocol and make Web development ressemble Desktop development. In an MVC application you never need to know anything like that.